# restricting the numbers of items to be added tosharepoint list per day

Tags: sharepoint

is there anyway that we could restrict the number of items to be added to a list for instance 30 items can be only added in 1 day. and then a message should appear if the number 31 tried to add new item, and tomorrow users will also be able to add 30 items and so on.
I found the below script that could limit the over all number of items to be added to 60.

```
<input type="button" value="Sign Up Now!" onclick="createItemIfBelowLimit()" />
<script>
function createItemIfBelowLimit(){
    var max = 60;
    var listTitle = "Your List Title";
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    clientContext.load(list);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var itemCount = list.get_itemCount();
        if(itemCount < max){
            createItem(listTitle,{
                "Title":"Example title text",
                "Body":"Example body text"
                });         
        }else{
            alert("This sign-up list is full. Sorry!");
        }
    },function(sender,args){
        alert(args.get_message());
    });
}
function createItem(listTitle,values){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var newItem = list.addItem();
    for(var key in values){
        newItem.set_item(key,values[key]);
    }
    newItem.update();
    clientContext.load(newItem);
    var rootFolder = list.get_rootFolder(); // Note: use a list's root folder to determine its server relative URL
    clientContext.load(rootFolder);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var itemId = newItem.get_item("ID");
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(
            { 
                title: "Item #"+itemId+" Created Successfully!", 
                url: rootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/DispForm.aspx?ID="+itemId
            }
        ); 
    },function(sender,args){
        alert(args.get_message());
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use SharePoint server object model then solid solution would be to implement SharePoint list item event receiver class based on SPItemEventReceiver class where you can override method

`public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)`

and then cancel adding new list item to list by using code:

```
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError;
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code as below to achieve it, add the CAML Query to get all today added items, and check the item count.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createItemIfBelowLimit, "sp.js");
function createItemIfBelowLimit(){
    var max = 30;
    var listTitle = "Your List Title";
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var query="<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'><Today/></Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(query);
    this.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(collListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var itemCount = collListItem.get_count();
        if(itemCount < max){
            createItem(listTitle,{
                "Title":"Example title text",
                "Body":"Example body text"
                });         
        }else{
            alert("This sign-up list is full. Sorry!");
        }
    },function(sender,args){
        alert(args.get_message());
    });
}
function createItem(listTitle,values){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var newItem = list.addItem();
    for(var key in values){
        newItem.set_item(key,values[key]);
    }
    newItem.update();
    clientContext.load(newItem);
    var rootFolder = list.get_rootFolder(); // Note: use a list's root folder to determine its server relative URL
    clientContext.load(rootFolder);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var itemId = newItem.get_item("ID");
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(
            { 
                title: "Item #"+itemId+" Created Successfully!", 
                url: rootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl() + "/DispForm.aspx?ID="+itemId
            }
        ); 
    },function(sender,args){
        alert(args.get_message());
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: We can use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded method to load the function, check the reply above.

Comment: note that the script didn't work, I still can add more than 30 items per day, thanks

Comment: did you try that from your end?

Comment: Where did you add the code? The code works when the page load.